# Are parentheses allowed in CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the below example, I want to create a CSS rule that applies only to the header with the text "Blockhead".

```
 <div class="gumby">
     <span class="pokey"></span>
     <h3>Blockhead</h3>
     <h3>Clay rules</h3>
 </div>
```

Can I use parentheses, such as `(.gumby > .pokey) + h3`?  If not, what is my alternative?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, parentheses are not valid operators in CSS selectors. They are reserved for functional notations, such as `:lang()`, `:not()`, and `:nth-child()`.

You don't need them anyway; `.gumby > .pokey + h3` by itself will work just fine.

This is because a sequence of selectors and combinators is always read [linearly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851635/css-combinator-precedence/3851754#3851754). Combinators don't have any sort of precedence. The selector can be interpreted as

> Select an `h3` element
>   that immediately follows an element with class `pokey`
>   that is a child of an element with class `gumby`.

And because of how node trees work, the use of sibling and child combinators here implies that both `.pokey` and the `h3` are children of `.gumby`, which in your case they are, because of its statement that both of them are siblings.

Comment: While "You don't need them anyway" is true, parentheses would help to avoid repetition, if they were allowed, like: `.gumby > (.hokey, .pokey) + h3`

Comment: @user686249: That role will be filled by the `:matches()` pseudo so there's no need for a brand new syntactic construct.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that one.

Comment: @BoltClock This comment is the actual answer.

Comment: @John: Not to this question. This question says nothing about grouping selectors, and the comment I was responding to was left by a completely different individual. You're probably thinking of something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771974/associating-multiple-selectors-with-a-pseudo-class, to which `:matches()` *is* the actual answer. (You *could* argue that it can be used for something like `:matches(.gumby > .pokey) + h3`, but that's completely redundant anyway since it has the exact same meaning as `.gumby > .pokey + h3`.)

Comment: :matches() was renamed to :is() in 2018 (Chrome & Firefox but not Edge).  https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3258, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

Answer (score 3):

As of 2022, we can now use the `:is()` selector for this purpose:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

```css
:is(.gumby > .pokey) + h3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="gumby">
     <span class="pokey"></span>
     <h3>Blockhead</h3>
     <h3>Clay rules</h3>
 </div>
```

If I understand correctly, `:is()` can simulate both logical AND `:is(A):is(B):is(C)` and logical OR `:is(A, B, C)`, allowing for powerful combinations. Don't forget to use it in concert with other structural pseudo-classes such as [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), CSS Combinators, and DOM Traversal methods such as [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
Also, the [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) pseudo-class is identical except that it has 0 specificity, while `:is()` takes the specificity of its most specific argument.

Answer (score 0):

h3 is not inside .pokey so you must ommit .pokey from the rule

All u'd be able to do is

```
.gumby h3 {}
```

or do this

```
 <div class="gumby pokey">
     <h3>Blockhead</h3>
     <h3>Clay rules</h3>
 </div>

.gumby.pokey h3 {}
```

if a tag has more than one class you can pile them up in css if you don't use a space character

Comment: Just realised this may not have been what you was asking for. My apologies

Comment: Thank you, But you are correct - this does not address the problem.