# CSS selector for specific rect in a SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-selectors

I'm trying to select all element from a SVG that follows a pattern to change the cursor for those elements :

Here is a code sample :

```
<g id="group418-1085" transform="translate(1975.93,-1403.11)" v:mID="418" v:groupContext="group">
        <v:custProps>
            <v:cp v:nameU="idApplication" v:lbl="idApplication" v:type="0" v:sortKey="1" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(216)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="labelFR" v:lbl="labelFR" v:type="0" v:sortKey="3" v:langID="1036"
                    v:val="VT4(Product Ref)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="labelEN" v:lbl="labelEN" v:type="0" v:sortKey="4" v:langID="1036"
                    v:val="VT4(Product entity)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="color" v:lbl="color" v:type="0" v:sortKey="99" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4()"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="type" v:lbl="type" v:type="0" v:sortKey="5" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(Business)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="name" v:lbl="name" v:type="0" v:sortKey="2" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(FundLife)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="External" v:lbl="External" v:type="0" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(FALSE)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="appLevel" v:lbl="appLevel" v:type="0" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(2)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="_VisDM_status" v:lbl="status" v:type="2" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT0(1):26"/>
        </v:custProps>
        <v:userDefs>
            <v:ud v:nameU="msvStructureType" v:prompt="" v:val="VT4(Container)"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="msvSDContainerMargin" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(0.078740157480315):24"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="Label" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(2):26"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="ShapeVersion" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(1):26"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="LightColorText" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(0):5"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="TechnicalVue" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(0):5"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="MainColor" v:prompt="" v:val="VT4(RGB(213;213;213))"/>
        </v:userDefs>
        <title>Application.51</title>
        <g id="shape419-1086" v:mID="419" v:groupContext="shape">
            <title>Feuille.419</title>
            <v:userDefs>
                <v:ud v:nameU="visVersion" v:val="VT0(14):26"/>
            </v:userDefs>
            <rect x="0" y="1641.26" width="113.386" height="42.5197" class="st56"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape418-1088" v:mID="418" v:groupContext="groupContent">
            <v:textBlock v:margins="rect(4,4,4,4)" v:tabSpace="42.5197"/>
            <v:textRect cx="56.6929" cy="1662.52" width="113.39" height="42.5197"/>
            <text x="44.24" y="1652.02" class="st4" v:langID="1036"><v:paragraph v:horizAlign="1"/><v:tabList/>FundLife<v:newlineChar/><v:newlineChar/><tspan
                        x="6.06" dy="2.4em" class="st55">Product referential for all entities of </tspan><tspan x="36.1"
                        dy="1.2em" class="st55">Owner</tspan></text>            </g>
    </g>
```

So what I'm trying to select is the `rect`.

The `rect`I wanna select are always children of a `g` that is a child of another `g` that has a descendant with a `v:nameU` attribute with the value `idApplication`.

(This descendant is always a `v:cp` child of a `v:custoProps` child of the `g` like in the code above, but I dont think it's necessary to use this.)

So I was thinking of :

```
g v:cp[v:nameU="idApplication"] > g > rect {cursor: help;}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: As far as I can see (in your code) there is never a `g` child for `idApplication`

Comment: You mean that `v:cp[v:nameU="idApplication"] > g` is calculated before `g v:cp[v:nameU="idApplication"]`
If so how can I set the priority to `g v:cp[v:nameU="idApplication"]` selector ?

Answer (score 1):

The `g` element that is the parent of the `rect` element is a following sibling of the `v:custProps` element containing the `v:cp` element in question:

```
<v:custProps>
    <v:cp v:nameU="idApplication" v:lbl="idApplication" v:type="0" v:sortKey="1" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(216)"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</v:custProps>
<!-- ... -->
<g id="shape419-1086" v:mID="419" v:groupContext="shape">
    <rect x="0" y="1641.26" width="113.386" height="42.5197" class="st56"/>
</g>
```

Since the `v:cp` element is a child of the `v:custProps`, while it is possible to represent the `v:cp` and `rect` elements separately like so:

```
@namespace v 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/';

g[id="group418-1085"] > v|custProps > v|cp[v|nameU="idApplication"] { /* ... */ }
g[id="group418-1085"] > v|custProps ~ g > rect { /* ... */ }
```

It is not possible to target the `rect` element based on that `v:cp` element in a single selector. Furthermore, combinators are linear and only accept two compound selectors at a time, and [you can't change this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757133/css-selector-for-adjacency/29765647#29765647), so it is not possible to combine the above two selectors into one.

(Also, to represent namespaced elements and attributes in selectors, you need to declare a namespace prefix and use the appropriate syntax as shown above, but that's a side issue and fixing it won't be of much use here.)

Comment: So it is not possible to do it this way ?
In that case is there a way to select every `rect`, children of a `g` directly following a `title` containing Application in its value ?

I don't know if we can parse the content of a tag or how to achieve this

Comment: @Ellone: You can't do that either, I'm afraid. I can't think of any other solutions.

Comment: I guess I will have to use javascript to set a class attribute to the matching elements somehow