# Associating multiple selectors with a pseudo-class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to have several selectors associated with a pseudo-class?

In other words, I want to make it so if an anchor, image, or button are hovered or focused on, they'll have a special border around them.

I tried this (shot in the dark):

```
(a,button,img):hover, (a,button,img):focus {
    border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

But Webstorm doesn't like it, and it doesn't activate.

I know that this works:

```
a:hover, a:focus {
    border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

But I'd like to be able to have it to apply to other selectors as well, without needing to repeat myself many times to apply it to all of them.

Comment: Maybe if you assign them all a common class (or) if you can use `*` (which I think is not quite what you want). Otherwise, pre-processors are your best bet.

Comment: Ugh, SO search sucks. Google isn't helping either. I've answered this same question (containing a very similar shot in the dark).

Comment: Fairly certain this is where pre-processors come into their own. You could make a modifier class that has the hover styles attached or you'd have to comma separate each element you want to attach the pseudo class to.

Comment: in order for CSS to be DRY, you are oing to need to use Preprocessors like SASS, LESS or Stylus

Comment: ... though technically that doesn't produce DRY CSS, it only lets you write DRY <whatever preprocessor flavor you use>

Comment: I'm not thinking this morning. It reality, I could have just use jQuery to set this up since it's a special case. Oh well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your shot in the dark is actually very close to what's proposed for Selectors 4, except it takes the form of its own pseudo-class, [`:matches()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches) (with the parentheses and the same comma-delimited syntax):

```
:matches(a, button, img):hover, :matches(a, button, img):focus {
    border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

which can be further simplified to:

```
:matches(a, button, img):matches(:hover, :focus) {
    border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

As it's not yet implemented outside of internal prefixes, you'll have to make do with writing it all out manually in the meantime:

```
a:hover, button:hover, img:hover,
a:focus, button:focus, img:focus {
    border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

Or make use of a preprocessor to do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Damn, thanks. I've been trying to avoid using preprocessors since this is just a toy site, and I really don't need them very much. Oh well, thanks.

Comment: It has now been renamed to: is() but works the same.