# Can I use brackets to separate multiple selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, logical-operators, brackets, multipleselection

I want to select first tag `a` nested under either div with class `article article_rubric_top` or with class `article article_top article_right`

I try:

```
$('div.article.article_rubric_top a:first,div.article.article_top.article_right a:first')
```

But get much less tags than expected. I wonder whether I should somehow separate nested tag selectors when I use multiple selectors?

Like this:

```
$('(div.article.article_rubric_top a:first),(div.article.article_top.article_right a:first)')
```

**Upd:** Minimal data example. I expect to match all three `a` tags.

```
<div class="article article_rubric_top">            
            <a href="http://ua.korrespondent.net/showbiz/music/3899530-duet-potap-i-nastia-zaiavyv-pro-te-scho-yde-zi-stseny" class="article__img-link"></a>           
</div>

<div class="article article_top article_right">

            <a href="http://ua.korrespondent.net/ukraine/3899526-ukraintsi-pochaly-chastishe-yizdyty-v-rosiui" class="article__img-link">
                <noscript><img src="https://kor.ill.in.ua/m/400x253/2072539.jpg"></noscript><img src="/i/blank.gif" data-href="https://kor.ill.in.ua/m/400x253/2072539.jpg" alt="Українці почали частіше їздити в Росію" class="article__img lzl"></a>         
</div>

<div class="article article_rubric_top">          
            <a href="http://ua.korrespondent.net/ukraine/3899521-likari-dozvolyly-prodovzhyty-sud-nad-kokhanivskym" class="article__img-link">
            </a>           
</div>
```

**Upd** For some reason minimal example does not work as my actual [example](https://ua.korrespondent.net/all/2017/october/24/p2/)

[Image of jquery run in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvNZc.png)

I get `div` and `a` tags instead of just `a` tags.

Comment: "Should" you? Since when was that allowed in the first place? Did I miss something?

Comment: @BoltClock, you have a point. Corrected. I need logical brackets and I ask whether there are ones?

Comment: Assuming that `()`  would be allowed for grouping in css, then both selector would most likely still produce the same result. So please show a minimal example where you get the wrong result, and explain what the result you expect, something like that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0q55axu5/4/)

Comment: @t.niese: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478920/are-parentheses-allowed-in-css-selectors/5478943#5478943)

Answer (score 0):

> I expect to match all three a tags.

Your selector should be `div.article a:first-child` - dont overcomplicate it with the specific classes. You have a perfectly valid shared class to target the appropriate `div` elements.

```js
$('.article a:first-child').css("background-color","yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article article_rubric_top">            
            <a href="http://ua.korrespondent.net/showbiz/music/3899530-duet-potap-i-nastia-zaiavyv-pro-te-scho-yde-zi-stseny" class="article__img-link">1</a>           
</div>

<div class="article article_top article_right">

            <a href="http://ua.korrespondent.net/ukraine/3899526-ukraintsi-pochaly-chastishe-yizdyty-v-rosiui" class="article__img-link">
                <noscript><img src="https://kor.ill.in.ua/m/400x253/2072539.jpg"></noscript><img src="/i/blank.gif" data-href="https://kor.ill.in.ua/m/400x253/2072539.jpg" alt="Українці почали частіше їздити в Росію" class="article__img lzl">2</a>         
</div>

<div class="article article_rubric_top">          
            <a href="http://ua.korrespondent.net/ukraine/3899521-likari-dozvolyly-prodovzhyty-sud-nad-kokhanivskym" class="article__img-link">3
            </a>           
</div>
```

Comment: As for jQuery and CSS having pseudos with the same name, if I really wanted to put the blame on one of them, it would be jQuery. The design of jQuery's :first pseudo completely subverts how selectors work. The :first pseudo in CSS is a page selector and really isn't relevant to the conversation since page selectors follow a separate grammar from the rest of the Selectors standard.

Comment: "The design of jQuery's :first pseudo completely subverts how selectors work." Case in point: this answer is wrong - `div.article a:first` will only ever match at most one `a` element - the first such element that matches `div.article a`.

Comment: @Boltclock I might have missed to make my point clear due to not being a native speaker. "put jQuery in bad light" was supposed to put the blame on jQuery. Glad to see the growing tendency to overcome jQuery as a dependency almost in every big OS library.

Comment: @BoltClock good spot (it was a lazy copy from the OP). Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. I've never tried, but I think there are better possibilities.

You could just simplify the selector

```
$(".article > a");
```

You could `join` an array

```
$([
    "div.article.article_rubric_top a:first",
    "div.article.article_top.article_right a:first"
].join(","))
```

I think that'd be far easier to work with than a longer string

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your selector like this:

`$('div.article.article_rubric_top,div.article.article_top.article_right').find('a:first')`

Here's a working snippet, I think this is what you wanted?

```js
$('div.article.article_rubric_top,div.article.article_top.article_right').find('a:first').css('border','1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article article_rubric_top">            
            <a href="http://ua.korrespondent.net/showbiz/music/3899530-duet-potap-i-nastia-zaiavyv-pro-te-scho-yde-zi-stseny" class="article__img-link">a</a>           
</div>

<div class="article article_top article_right">

            <a href="http://ua.korrespondent.net/ukraine/3899526-ukraintsi-pochaly-chastishe-yizdyty-v-rosiui" class="article__img-link">b
                <noscript><img src="https://kor.ill.in.ua/m/400x253/2072539.jpg"></noscript><img src="/i/blank.gif" data-href="https://kor.ill.in.ua/m/400x253/2072539.jpg" alt="Українці почали частіше їздити в Росію" class="article__img lzl"></a>         
</div>

<div class="article article_rubric_top">          
            <a href="http://ua.korrespondent.net/ukraine/3899521-likari-dozvolyly-prodovzhyty-sud-nad-kokhanivskym" class="article__img-link">c
            </a>
</div>
```