# Select and not select specific element with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I have a HTML structure like this:

```html
<article class="post-content-area post type-post status-publish hentry"> 
    <div class="some-class">
        <div class="entry-content">
            content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

or

```html
<article class="post-content-area post type-post status-publish hentry"> 
    <div class="entry-content">
        content goes here
    </div>
</article>
```

I need to select `entry-content` class that is inside a tag with `post-content-area post type-post status-publish hentry` classes, regardless of how nested `entry-content` is.

I've tried `document.querySelectorAll("(post-content-area.post.type-post.status-publish.hentry)> .entry-content")`

but it didn't work

Comment: Try this `document.querySelectorAll(".post-content-area.post.type-post.status-publish.hentry .entry-content")`

Comment: If you are still unsure of why your selector does not work, check out: [What does the “>” (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)

Comment: By the way, using parenthesis for a selector is not allowed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478920/are-parentheses-allowed-in-css-selectors

Comment: @HassanImam that's what I needed. thank you so much