# What's the precedence of the + operator in CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

[From the CSS selector spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching):

> E + F matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E.

What about operator precedence? What does `#id1 #id2 + #id3` match?
What about `#id1 + #id2 #id3?`

Is there a selector that means `#id1 (#id2 + #id3)` or `(#id1 + #id2) #id3`?
(I'm assuming `(` and `)` aren't really allowed in CSS selectors, I'm not seeing them in the spec)

Comment: What would the difference be, between for example `#id1 (#id2 + #id3)` and `(#id1 #id2) + #id3`?

Comment: @BoltClock - true that, there isn't a difference.

Comment: @BoltClock on the other hand, given a (rather confusing) selector like `#id1 #id2 + #id3 #id4` the precedence *does* matter; the example given in this question might be bad, but the core of the question is still good.

Comment: @Mark Amery: So it matters when you have no fewer than two descendant combinators. Yeah, that's a better example.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Every sequence of simple selectors and combinators is read by browsers from right to left, in a linear fashion. Combinators do not affect the ordering in any way. The rightmost selector, after the last combinator if any, is known as the *key selector* (see the reference links below for more), and that identifies the element that the rule applies to (also known as the *subject* of the selector, although note that the key selector may not always represent the subject of the selector, since different applications implement selectors differently).

The selector `#id1 #id2 + #id3` means

> Select element `#id3`
>   if it directly follows as a sibling of `#id2`
>   that is a descendant of `#id1`.

A DOM structure in which `#id3` would match the selector would look like this:

```
#id1
  ... any level of nesting
    #id2
    #id3
```

While `#id1 + #id2 #id3` means

> Select element `#id3`
>   if it is a descendant of `#id2`
>   that directly follows as a sibling of `#id1`.

And a DOM structure in which `#id3` would match the selector would look like this:

```
#id1
#id2
  ... any level of nesting
    #id3
```

Notice the difference in the position of element `#id2` in this DOM structure, as compared to the one above.

There isn't much of a precedence issue here since the descendant and sibling combinators go in different directions in the DOM. Both selector sequences read right to left either way.

Related answers:

- [CSS combinator precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851635/css-combinator-precedence/3851754#3851754)
- [Are parentheses allowed in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478920/css-selector-are-parentheses-allowed/5478943#5478943)
- [CSS Adjacent Selector / Meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886900/css-adjacent-selector-meaning/6887175#6887175)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I believe even if parenthesis were allowed, then the expressions `#id1 (#id2 + #id3)` and `(#id1 #id2) + #id3` would be equivalent. Am I right?