# Why use ">" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, styles, paradigms

If I want to add styling to all p elements inside of a div, why should I use

```
div > p{

  *style here*

}
```

as opposed to just

```
div p{

  *style here*

}
```

furthermore, if I want to use a pseudo class, why would I then choose to use ">"

```
div > p:first-child{

  *style here*

}
```

instead of

```
 div p:first-child{

   *style here*

 }
```

Are there any benefits or drawbacks?
what does that operator do?

Comment: If you [*read the specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) you could find out all this stuff.. and ask a more refined/focused question, should any questions remain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ">" mean in CSS rules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the direct child, not a recursive match.

**CSS**

```
div > p {

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <p>Match</p>
   <span>
      <p>No match</p>
   </span>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
div p {

}
```

**Markup**

```
<div>
   <p>Match</p>
   <span>
      <p>Match</p>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: [Child Combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) (from the W3 CSS3 spec)

Comment: but isn't the > unnecessary if i have :first-child after the p in my stylesheet?

Comment: :first-child is for first child only. > is for all direct childes :)

Comment: ahh took me a while to understand, direct child just means the p is not nested within another element inside the div.  for some reason, "direct child" registered to me as "first child". thanks for this.

Comment: You really shouldn't wrap a `p` in a `span` though. The browser may do something unexpected with that.

Comment: @steveax it's meant to demonstrate the concept of the combinator, not block vs inline constraints.

Comment: @Gabe yes, but since it's not valid, the browser may close that span tag before the p.

Comment: @steveax, Yes, I know. Thanks for reiterating it. Like I said it was a conceptual example.

Answer (score 3):

Because it means direct child.

Your second example would match the `p` in this example

```
<div>
  <header>
    <p>
    </p>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`>` and  (space) are *relationship selectors* meaning "child" and "descendant" respectively. On top of the semantic differences others have pointed out, a child selector [computes faster as it avoids redundant DOM tree traversal on non-matching elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11218698/1081234).