# More CSS, less HTML?

Tags: css, performance, html

Which is better performance wise?

```
<a class="btn loginbtn" href="#">Login</a>​

.btn {
    background: #555 
}
.loginbtn {
    padding: 10px
}​
```

**or**

```
<a class="loginbtn" href="#">Login</a>​

.btn,.loginbtn {
    background: #555  
}
.loginbtn {
    padding: 10px     
}​
```

Since my CSS will be cached I was thinking the second one would be better.

Help me out please.

Comment: You can use Google Chrome, open the developer tools, select Profiles -> Collect CSS selector Profile and see which selector is faster (if it makes a difference at all).

Comment: This is not a bad question, if only for the lack of specifics and references of previous research. Don't let the downvotes make you think otherwise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate the average performance difference caused by the difference in file size as the time it would take to fetch one more TCP/IP package times the probability that it would happen because of that change (i.e. package size divived by the number of characters added).

You might get something like `10 ms * 1/1000`, which would give you `10 µs`.

That is such a small performance difference that you have to make the same thing a huge number of times before it's noticable.

So, you should use the one that is clearer and easier to maintain.

Personally I would go with the first option. I find it easier to see what's applied to the element if there is a single path to follow from the class names to the rules, rather than having a class scattered across several rules.

Comment: Alright thanks everyone, I'm going to use the 1st method because the second one, when it gets big, it gives me headaches. Not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two would be very marginal, I'd be more concerned about code maintainability and *maybe* [selector performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218699/1081234).

If you're really in a position where the benefit from individual bytes shaved off html adds up to something significant, you may want to check [closure-stylesheets](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/) that supports CSS class renaming among other things.