# Why does jQuery UI use nested css classes?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Why does jQuery UI write CSS like this:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {}
```

Since their class names are so descriptive I would think it faster and just as unlikely to have any collisions if they did this:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {}
.ui-dialog-content {}
```

It seems to me they are nesting classes unnecessarily and causing the browser to do more work but I wonder if there's a good reason for it that I'm not aware of. Does anyone know why they nest the classes as they do?

Comment: "they are nesting classes unnecessarily and causing the browser to do more work". I think the amount of work a browser has to do there is quite trivial.

Comment: When you create a library like this, I think you'd consider such things though because they can be used many times over. It's also downloaded A LOT making bandwidth an issue.

Comment: The bandwidth issue is pretty much non existent.  `.ui-dialog` takes up about 10 bytes? 10 bytes x 1 million downloads = 9 megabytes

Comment: @CHS The reason is most likely a specificity issue, though you are more likely to get an answer about this directly from the core team if you ask it either in the jQuery UI forum or on the jQuery UI IRC channel. All we can do here is speculate why they did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do this to be specific.

The element with the class `.ui-dialog-content` also has several other classes such as `.ui-widget-content`.

```
<div id="dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
```

To ensure that the rules of `.ui-dialog-content` trump those of the other classes they add `.ui-dialog` infront.

This is evident when you inspect the element.  The background and border rules of `.ui-widget-content` will be overridden.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.ui-widget-content {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f2f5f7_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% top #F2F5F7; /* Overridden */
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; /*Overridden*/
    color: #362B36;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/457N8/ Can you show me which element on this fiddle you see ui-widget-content 's background being overwritten?

Comment: It is the div containing "hello".  The html in my post was from a dialog shown via a button.  It's not just the background either.  It also removes the border.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that would happen. I need to brush up my understanding of CSS rules it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely because the CSS for `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close` and `.ui-dialog-content` is reusable. So basically they are ensuring these classes will only inherit specific styles to the dialog when they are children of `.ui-dialog`

Comment: The thing is I don't think they are reusable. You'd never see them used outside of the dialog widget in the ui namespace, hence their naming conventions.

Comment: @CHS that doesn't stop you from using them yourself for your ui, or for a custom widget.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct about the fact that [shallow, preferrably one-level selectors are preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218699/1081234) - at least from the performance perspective, at least in theory. However in most cases rendering engine optimizations offset the otherwise miniscule performance overhead.

This is when ease of maintenance, readability and size of the stylesheet kicks in. Reduced specificity allows to recycle "partial" classes - if you [look at the rendered markup](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), `.ui-dialog` will have a whole bunch of other classes applied to it:

```
ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable
```

Would it have been preferable to instead have all the properties applied in *one* rule? Definitely not from the developer point of view, that approach would have made it into a maintenance nightmare. Imagine changing a single presentational property and then having to backdate it to all "specific" rules like in your example!

The reasoning for qualifying the ansector selector (e.g. `.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content`) is a lot more trivial, if not immediately obvious - to increase specificity of these selectors. For instance, `.ui-helper-reset` class basically anulls any previously set style since the rule is declared at the bottom of the css file:

```
.ui-helper-reset {
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.3;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To override any of those properties, a higher-specificity selector has to be used.

Personally I dislike this pattern - and I hope that code consistency contributed more to the reasoning behind such class structure.