# CSS Performance with Compound Selectors and Right-to-Left Parsing

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

I cannot find in the official docs, or within any of the many articles I've read how CSS is parsed with compound selectors.

*Side note: Obviously there are reasons for compound selectors in some specificity needs; and yes, descendant selectors are expensive.*

Most articles simply validate that CSS is read right-to-left like this:

```
div.some-class li a
```

The authors of these articles state something like:

> First, all anchor elements are matched, then the parser looks for a list-item as an ancestor, then it looks for an ancestor div with the class of "some-class."

In these descriptions, it is appearing that the CSS parser looks at space-separated combinators as single units instead of reading right-to-left within a given compound selector.

So a very common argument I see online and at work is that `div.some-class` is faster than `.some-class` because, "It only has to look at `div`s that have that class."  But, that would only make sense if CSS was read left-to-right, OR if in a compound selector there's an exception for better performance that it finds the element collection first before seeing if there's a matching class.

However, using the example above, my understanding is this:

> All `a` elements are matched, then if there is an `li` ancestor it's still matched, then it looks for ANY ELEMENT ancestor with a class of "some-class", THEN it checks if that element is a `div`.  If so, the styles will be applied.

**The real question:**

1) Is `div.some-class` still read right-to-left in that compound form; or,

2) as a compound selector, does the CSS parser find all ancestor `div`s first, then see if they have that class?

An official source of the answer is what I'm most interested in.

**Possible answer:** Assuming the `document.querySelectorAll` uses the CSS parsing engine and not a JavaScript "version" of it, I found the following:

> Based on a test I did with 200,000 `p` elements on a page, and all with the class of "p" on them.  Querying `.p` repeated in a loop 100X, vs `p.p` showed that `.p` is the fastest in Chrome 53.  Selecting `p.p` takes 1.71X as long.
>   I repeated the process 8 times and averaged the numbers to get the difference. `.p` = 2,358 ms and `p.p` = 4,036 ms.

```
function p() {
    var d = Date.now();
    var a = [];
    var i = 0;
    function fn() {
        a.push(document.querySelectorAll(".p").length);
    }
    for (;i<100;i++) {
        fn();
    }
    console.log(".p = " + (Date.now() - d));
}

function pp() {
    var d = Date.now();
    var a = [];
    var i = 0;
    function fn() {
        a.push(document.querySelectorAll("p.p").length);
    }
    for (;i<100;i++) {
        fn();
    }
    console.log("p.p = " + (Date.now() - d));
}
```

In Chrome 53, it appears that compound selectors are in fact still read right-to-left, making element.class compound selectors much slower than selecting by class alone, and the same with attributes instead of classes.

In IE11, it's mostly the inverse.  Though not significantly faster, compound selectors with `element.class` or `element[attribute]` were actually faster than getting an the elements by class or attribute alone.

Comment: "I cannot find in the official docs [...] how CSS is parsed with combinators." Because that's an implementation detail that has no bearing on standards compliance. The spec does not tell implementers how to implement the spec, it just gives them the rules and they do whatever they need to do to comply. An implementation could evaluate selectors LTR and it would still be considered standards-compliant, albeit inefficient. Also, what you call "combinator units" are known in the spec as compound selectors.

Comment: element.class - assuming "element" is a type selector - is not a fair test since type selectors are required by the grammar to appear first. Neither can you compare element.class with just .class and conclude that the directionality of selector evaluation has anything to do with the results (more likely, the overhead of having to evaluate one more condition every time is what's making p.p slower). Have you tried comparing .class#id and #id.class, .class[attr] and [attr].class, or even .class:pseudo-class and :pseudo-class.class?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106345/which-direction-do-selector-engines-read

Comment: Re-reading your question now I'm not so sure you're using the term "combinators" correctly. Are you referring to compound selectors or combinators? They are two completely different things. The spaces you mention, *those* are combinators, as are >, + and ~. But joining two simple selectors together is not a combinator. Furthermore, combinators have *no effect on specificity* - element.class and element .class are equally specific regardless of the space. The distinction is important because implementations *do* handle these completely differently.

Comment: @BoltClock Great comments.  I updated my post with the correct terminology and added attribute test results and IE's (somewhat) surprising differences.  I think your "implementation detail that has no bearing on standards compliance" would be my accepted answer with a well-pointed-out second comment about the accuracy of the test and other SO link.  Thanks!

Comment: Unless your interest is theoretical, none of this is likely to make any difference in the real-world performance of your app. You should write CSS classes and rules which are well-structured and readable and semantic, and then and only then do benchmarks and profiles to determine if there are performance issues worth addressing.

Comment: @torazaburo While CSS selecting is very fast, we're at a point in our very heavy/rich web apps that CSS rendering (and also JavaScript querySelecting) is notably slow, so any performance boost we can get is worth it for us.  At this point though, it's mostly about making sure future code is as fast as we can reasonably make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compound selectors are not necessarily evaluated in any specific order. For example, most if not all implementations optimize for ID, class and type selectors to match fast or fail fast (at least Gecko does [according to Boris Zbarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left/5813672#5813672)), *then* evaluate attribute selectors and pseudo-classes as necessary.

It's not feasible to predict how exactly any given browser, let alone all of them, will evaluate a compound selector, let alone each compound selector in a complex selector containing more than one, but what we *do* know is that right-to-left matching starts from the rightmost compound selector and steps leftward until matching fails.

It's important to note that this is merely an implementation detail that's agreed upon by vendors — you could implement selector matching however you like, but so long as you match the right elements with the right selectors, your implementation will be standards-compliant.

But what's most important is that, in the real world, none of this is likely to matter. Write selectors that are readable and meaningful, don't unnecessarily overqualify them, avoid specificity hacks where possible, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear that `querySelectorAll` is a valid way of testing the performance of basic CSS matching, since they are two separate problems: whereas `querySelectorAll` is trying to find elements matching some selector, basic CSS matching is trying to find the selector matching some element. It is entirely possible that they are implemented quite differently internally. For instance, if I was implementing `querySelectorAll('div span')`, I might choose to **first** find all the `div` elements, and then find `span` descendants, whereas if I was trying to find the rule to match the `<span>` in `<div><span></span></div>`, I would look for rules **ending** in `span`, then check their ancestors.

Having said that, if you have performance problems with your CSS, I would suggest that rather than concerning yourself with internal details of the CSS engine, such as the order in which the components of `p.p` are matched, you might be better off going back and reviewing some basic principles of your CSS. In particular, in case you are using SASS etc., make sure you are not falling into the temptation of overly qualified, overly nested selectors, such as would be generated by structures which unnecessarily mirror the structure of the HTML, as in

```
.page-content {
  .article {
    .section {
      .quote {
```

It could easily be the case that a single rule for `.quote` is all you need, without the ancestor qualifiers. As a very general rule, CSS architectures involving independent, single-purpose classes which are composed are going to perform better than ones with long chains of selectors trying to match HTML structure.

In addition, make sure you are following basic best practices such as not specifying the element type when it is not necessary, such as is often the case with `div.div` instead of just `.div`.

Of course, you should find and weed out unused rules if you haven't already done that.