# Selecting multiple adjacent siblings (and their children)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I change the styles of my div's 2 siblings when hovering over it?

```
#magic:hover + (#sibling1 > span, #sibling2 > span){color: blue}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKF5p/)

Comment: See also: [Are parentheses allowed in CSS selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478920/are-parentheses-allowed-in-css-selectors) and [CSS combinator precedence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851635/css-combinator-precedence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use adjacent selector to achieve that?

```
#magic:hover + #sibling1 + #sibling2 span {
    color: red;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RKF5p/3/)</kbd> *(Hover the first element and see the color changes for the 3rd element)*

And if you want to change the styles of all the element followed by `#magic`, than use

```
#magic:hover + #sibling1 span,
#magic:hover + #sibling1 + #sibling2 span {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/RKF5p/4/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKF5p/2/)

```
#magic:hover ~ .box span {color: blue}
```

edited use the above instead, apparently + only works with immediate sibling http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/adjacent-sibling-selector-css-selector/

Comment: Unfortunately, this only changes the first sibling's style

Comment: This will select the following siblings, you can't select earlier siblings with css alone.